# Flex item wrapping to next line on reducing the width of container - CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

Following is my code, In which I want 3 `.item` divs to be on one line and next 3 on other. Below mentioned code is working fine for normal screen. But as soon as I reduce the size of browser 2 items are displaying on a single row. Let me know what I am doing wrong here though I have added width to be 33% and it should be accommodating it but may be I am missing something here.

Code -

```css
:root { box-sizing: border-box; }
.flex { display: flex; width: 100%; flex-wrap: wrap; }
.item { flex: 0 1 33%; border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item">Flex Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Flex Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Flex Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Flex Item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Flex Item 5</div>
  <div class="item">Flex Item 6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You forgot to take account of the size of the borders. Have you tried adding `box-sizing: border-box;` to your items ?

Comment: @AmauryHanser oh man ..you made my day ..lol :) Thx it helped...pleas add this in answer and I will accept yours :)

Comment: done. I'm glad it helped! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding `box-sizing: border-box` to your items, you'll make sure that their width won't grow over 33%.

Without it, their width is equal to 33% + 1px + 1px. At some point, it will be more than a third of their parent width.

```
:root { box-sizing: border-box; }
.flex { display: flex; width: 100%; flex-wrap: wrap; }
.item { flex: 0 1 33%; border: 1px solid red; box-sizing: border-box; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Amaury Hanser is right - adding `box-sizing: border-box;` to the items will resolve your problem.

An alternative though is to use `grid` instead of `flex`. This allows you to use the `1fr` unit, which automatically takes into account factors like padding and border size when equally distributing the width to the specified number columns.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">Flex Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Flex Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Flex Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Flex Item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Flex Item 5</div>
  <div class="item">Flex Item 6</div>
</div>
```